# How to efficiently do aggregate on sparse data

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, sparse-matrix

I have a large dataset with 1008412 observations,
the columns are `customer_id` (int), `visit_date` (Date, format: "2010-04-04"), `visit_spend` (float).

This date function for the aggregate maps week numbers of interest to the range 13-65:

```
weekofperiod <- function(dt) {
    as.numeric(format(as.Date(dt), "%W")) + 52 * (as.numeric(format(as.Date(dt), "%Y"))-2010)
}
```

Each customer_id has a variable number of total visits over a 53-week period.
For each `customer_id`, I want to get the aggregate of `spend_per_week`, by `weekofperiod()`. 
The code below is functionally correct but very slow - comments to make it faster?
Also, `aggregate()` produces sparse output where weeks without visits are missing, I initialize `spend_per_week` to 0, then row-wise manually assign the non-zero results from aggregate(), to make sure the result always has 53 rows. Surely that can be done better?

Sample dataset lines look like:

```
   customer_id visit_date visit_spend 
72          40 2011-03-15       18.38 
73          40 2011-03-20       23.45  
74          79 2010-04-07      150.87 
75          79 2010-04-17      101.90 
76          79 2010-05-02      111.90
```

and here's the code with aggregate call and adjustment for empty weeks:

```
for (cid in all_tt_cids) {
  print_pnq('Getting statistics for cid', cid)

  # Get row indices of the selected subset, for just this cid's records
  I <- which(tt$customer_id==cid & tt$visit_date<="2011-03-31")

  # (other code to compute other per-cid statistics)

  # spend_per_week (mode;mean;sd)
  # Aggregate spend_per_week, but beware this should be 0 for those week with no visits
  spend_per_week <- data.frame(c(list('weekofperiod'=13:65), list('spendperweek'=0)) )
  nonzero_spends_per_week <- aggregate(tt$visit_spend[I], list('weekofperiod'=weekofperiod(tt$visit_date[I])), FUN="sum")
  for (i in 1:nrow(nonzero_spends_per_week)) {
    spend_per_week[spend_per_week$weekofperiod==nonzero_spends_per_week[i,1],2] <- nonzero_spends_per_week[i,2]
  }
  colnames(spend_per_week)[2] <- 'spend_per_week'

  # (code to compute and store per-cid statistics on spend_per_week)

}
```

Comment: What is the source of the raw data? A sql database? For pure speed I'd remcommend using the database engine and return ready to display results. This query is not overly complex and could be handled in SQL.

Comment: Plain .csv. I'm trying to compute like 50 different statistics per customer_id (that's the code that was omitted), so it wouldn't make sense to do just this calculation in sqldf. So my constraint is native R language.

Comment: @John Colby's answer below is nice.  It could probably be sped up further using something from `data.table`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your biggest speed up is going to come if you **replace the `for` loops**. I can't quite tell from your example, because you overwrite each customer in the loop, but here's one way to do it if you want to keep the info for all subjects.

For testing, first define functions for the original method, and a new method without loops:

```
weekofperiod <- function(dt) {
  as.numeric(format(as.Date(dt), "%W")) + 52 * (as.numeric(format(as.Date(dt), "%Y"))-2010)
}

FastMethod <- function(tt) {  
  tt$week = weekofperiod(tt$visit_date)
  spend_per_week.tmp = as.data.frame(tapply(tt$visit_spend, tt[,c(1,4)], sum))
  spend_per_week = data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=nrow(spend_per_week.tmp), ncol=length(13:65)))
  colnames(spend_per_week) = 13:65
  rownames(spend_per_week) = rownames(spend_per_week.tmp)
  spend_per_week[, colnames(spend_per_week.tmp)] = spend_per_week.tmp
  spend_per_week
}

OrigMethod <- function(tt) {
  all_tt_cids = unique(tt$customer_id)

  for (cid in all_tt_cids) {
    # Get row indices of the selected subset, for just this cid's records
    I <- which(tt$customer_id==cid & tt$visit_date<="2011-03-31")

    # Aggregate spend_per_week, but beware this should be 0 for those week with no visits
    spend_per_week <- data.frame(c(list('weekofperiod'=13:65), list('spendperweek'=0)))
    nonzero_spends_per_week <- aggregate(tt$visit_spend[I], list('weekofperiod'=weekofperiod(tt$visit_date[I])), FUN="sum")
    for (i in 1:nrow(nonzero_spends_per_week)) {
      spend_per_week[spend_per_week$weekofperiod==nonzero_spends_per_week[i,1],2] <- nonzero_spends_per_week[i,2]
    }
    colnames(spend_per_week)[2] <- 'spend_per_week'
  }
  spend_per_week
}
```

Now simulate a larger dataset so it's easier to compare:

```
n.row  = 10^4
n.cust = 10^3

customer_id = 1:n.cust
dates = seq(as.Date('2010-04-01'), as.Date('2011-03-31'), by=1)
visit_date = sample(dates, n.row, replace=T)
visit_spend = runif(n.row, 0, 200)

tt = data.frame(customer_id, visit_date, visit_spend)
```

Finally, compare the two methods:

```
> system.time(FastMethod(tt))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.082   0.001   0.083 
> system.time(OrigMethod(tt))

   user  system elapsed 
  4.505   0.007   4.514
```

This is already **50x faster**, and I bet you can make it even better with more optimization. Good luck!

Comment: Very nice but can you get rid of the NAs from `spend_per_week.tmp = as.data.frame(tapply(tt$visit_spend, tt[,c(1,4)], sum))` ?

Comment: In fact it's easiest to propagate the NAs into `spend_per_week`, then remove them: `for (w in 1:ncol(spend_per_week)) spend_per_week[is.na(spend_per_week[,w]), w] <- 0`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a faster method using `data.table`, which is also easier to read.

```
FasterMethod <- function(tt){
  # LOAD LIBRARIES
  require(reshape2)
  require(data.table)
  tt <- transform(tt, week_of_period = weekofperiod(visit_date))

  # AGGREGATE SPEND BY CUSTOMER AND WEEK OF PERIOD
  tt <- data.table(tt)
  ans <- tt[,list(spend = sum(visit_spend)), 'customer_id, week_of_period']

  # RESHAPE TO CUSTOMER ID VS. WEEK OF PERIOD
  dcast(ans, customer_id ~ week_of_period, value_var = 'spend')
}
```

We can benchmark this against `FastMethod` and `OrigMethod` using `rbenchmark`, and see that we gain a 1.3x speedup over `FastMethod` and an overall speedup of 70x

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(FastMethod(tt), FasterMethod(tt), replications = 40)

test             elapsed relative 
FastMethod(tt)    5.594  1.346654     
FasterMethod(tt)  4.154  1.000000
```

You can speed it up even further (2.5 x compared to `FastMethod`) if you did not care about reshaping the final output to customer id vs. week of period.